# image uploading is too slow even after compress with js (uploading with php)

Tags: javascript, php, file-upload, image-compression

Here is the image compression code, which is working fine.
I am appending image base64 code to formdata and sending ahead to php for uploading, but it is taking too much time to upload yet.
it's 150KB image after compression, and 5MB before compression.
any solution for fast upload after compression???

```
var i=0;
function Resize()
{
    // $("#ChoosenImageImg").attr('src','');
    var filesToUpload = document.getElementById('Pimage').files;
    var file = filesToUpload[0];
    var dataurl='';
    i++;
    // Create an image
    var img = document.createElement("img");
    // Create a file reader
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // Set the image once loaded into file reader
    reader.onload = function(e) {
            img.src = e.target.result;

            var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            //var canvas = $("<canvas>", {"id":"testing"})[0];
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

            var MAX_WIDTH = 350;
            var MAX_HEIGHT = 350;
            var width = img.width;
            var height = img.height;

            if (width > height) {
                if (width > MAX_WIDTH) {
                    height *= MAX_WIDTH / width;
                    width = MAX_WIDTH;
                }
            } else {
                if (height > MAX_HEIGHT) {
                    width *= MAX_HEIGHT / height;
                    height = MAX_HEIGHT;
                }
            }

            canvas.width = width;
            canvas.height = height;
            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);

            dataurl = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
            // return dataurl;
            // document.getElementById('output').src = dataurl;
            $("#ChoosenImage").html('<img id="ChoosenImageImg" src="'+dataurl+'" width="175px" height="160px"> ');
            // alert(dataurl);
        }
        // Load files into file reader
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);

    if(i<=1)
    {
      Resize();
    }
}

--------------------------------------------

File Uploading Code

if($this->input->post('ImageResult') && $this->input->post('ImageResult') !='')
        {
            $img = $this->input->post('ImageResult');
            $data = $img;

            list($type, $data) = explode(';', $data);
            list(, $data) = explode(',', $data);
            $data = base64_decode($data);


            $dp = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
            // $target_path = $dp . "assets/patient_images/".basename($Filename);

            $ImageName = 'Patient'.rand(100,90000);
            $ImageName = $ImageName.'_'.rand(100,90000);
            $ImageName = $ImageName.'.png';

            file_put_contents($dp."assets/patient_images/".$ImageName, $data);


            $return = $this->Operatormodel->AddPatient($ImageName, $Alldata);
                echo $return;
        }
```

Comment: Question not clear

Comment: Sumesh TG1 | image uploading time is too much, 30 to 40 seconds per image.. if the image is greater than 4MB.

Comment: even after compression.. :/

Answer (score 0):

Base64 expands your data. Send the binary data directly.